Member signature overloading with nullable generics & constraints exhibiting unusual behavior
This is unexpected, behavior I'm finding with method overloads, nullable/non-nullable generics, and generic constraints.
It's my understanding that generic constraints do not affect method signatures. However, evidence below seems to indicate this is not the case? At least for these examples. That or I'm grossly misunderstanding things.
This is even confirmed by previous questions such as:

Member with the same signature already defined with different type constraints

For posterity & searchability, the relevant error here is:

Member with the same signature is already declared


 These are contrived examples based on some marginally related code. Please keep this in mind.

Signatures Examples 1
// Here was can see that A, B, & C are valid overloads, but D is not.
public class Foo<TEntity, TDto>
{
    // A - ✅
    Foo<TEntity, TDto> Property<TMember>(Func<TEntity, TMember?> memberA,
        Func<TDto, TMember?> memberB,
        Func<TMember?, Status> setter)
        where TMember : IComparable, IComparable<TMember> { }

    // B - ✅
    Foo<TEntity, TDto> Property<TMember>(Func<TEntity, TMember> memberA,
        Func<TDto, TMember?> memberB,
        Func<TMember?, Status> setter)
        where TMember : struct { }
    
    // C - ✅
    Foo<TEntity, TDto> Property<TMember>(Func<TEntity, TMember> memberA,
        Func<TDto, TMember?> memberB,
        Func<TMember, Status> setter)
        where TMember : struct { }
    
    // D - ❌ Duplicate Signature as A
    // Why, of all 4, is this the duplicate signature?
    Foo<TEntity, TDto> Property<TMember>(Func<TEntity, TMember> memberA,
        Func<TDto, TMember> memberB,
        Func<TMember, Status> setter)
        where TMember : struct { }
}

Signatures Examples 2
// Here was can see that A & B are duplicate signatures
// However, in Example #1 Method B is an acceptable overload, in this example it is not. Despite the arguments being the same. 
public class Foo<TEntity, TDto>
{
    // A - ✅
    Foo<TEntity, TDto> Property<TMember>(Func<TEntity, TMember?> memberA,
        Func<TDto, TMember?> memberB,
        Func<TMember?, Status> setter)
        where TMember : IComparable, IComparable<TMember> { }

    // B - ❌ Duplicate Signature as A
    //  Well, that's odd. This is the same as Example #1-B, the only difference being the generic constraint
    //    This overload is disallowed here, but allowed when the generic constraint is instead "struct". Why?
    Foo<TEntity, TDto> Property<TMember>(Func<TEntity, TMember> memberA,
        Func<TDto, TMember?> memberB,
        Func<TMember?, Status> setter)
        where TMember : IComparable, IComparable<TMember> { }
    
    // C - ✅ (The same as B, but with a different generic constraint, to illustrate the point)
    Foo<TEntity, TDto> Property<TMember>(Func<TEntity, TMember> memberA,
        Func<TDto, TMember?> memberB,
        Func<TMember?, Status> setter)
        where TMember : struct { }
}


My Questions Are:

What is the behavior I'm observing here? I was under the impression that generic constraints had no affect on overloads.
Why is Example 1 Method D seemingly an exception to the "rule" here? Why is that not a valid overload, which B & C are?

